# How to remove Django`s BinaryField from memory?

Tags: python, django, memory, deferred

I have a Django model with `BinaryField`:

```
class MyData(models.Model):
    someData = models.CharField()
    data = models.BinaryField()
```

In my app I need to iterate over the big set of rows. Of course I mark binary field as deferred:

```
myDataList = MyData.objects().filter(...).defer('data')
for myData in myDataList:
    doSmthWithData(myData.data)
    ...
```

The result of the initial request requires small amount of memory. But while I iterate over the query set I fetch binary data from the database. Because of the size of the binary fields, memory is quickly exhausted.

We can do a trick to free the memory - at the end of loop set `data` to `None`: `myData = None`. But in this case to modify and save entity I need to query it again from the database, otherwise binary data will be lost.

Do we have any other way to delete binary data from the memory? Something like: `set_defer(myData.data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [iterator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#iterator) like this.

```
myDataList = MyData.objects().filter(...).defer('data')
for myData in myDataList.iterator():
    doSmthWithData(myData.data)
```

> Evaluates the QuerySet (by performing the query) and returns an iterator (see PEP 234) over the results. A QuerySet typically caches its results internally so that repeated evaluations do not result in additional queries. In contrast, iterator() will read results directly, without doing any caching at the QuerySet level (internally, the default iterator calls iterator() and caches the return value). For a QuerySet which returns a large number of objects that you only need to access once, this can result in better performance and a significant reduction in memory.